# Is there any way for ansible dynamic inventory script to actually return an inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I want to create dynamic ansible directory and was reading and researching about it.

I found in the documentation that it is totally possible to create the inventory dynamically by using any language and executing it as a script and returning json response

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html

I want to achieve the following:
Run ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i myscript.sh

And the result of myscript.sh will be a text file like a normal inventory file

```
[mailserver]
someip ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=ddd ansible_ssh_pass=afaf
```

It is easier for me to generate such files where the vars like `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`  ansible_port, ssh_user etc are defined than creating a json.

I can create the inventory using other programming language but from the doc I see it supports only json output somehow

PS:
I tried using something like
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory.sh

and the content of inventory.sh being

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cat << EOF >
[mailserver]
someip ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=dd.pem

EOF
```

But it did not work as expected the result to be yaml

```
inventory.sh with yaml plugin: YAML inventory has
invalid structure, it should be a dictionary,
```

I find it very amusing and strange that you can return json and yaml, but not the default format of inventory as plain text...

Comment: `And the result of myscript.sh will be a text file like a normal inventory file` This is the description of a script spitting out a a static inventory file, not of a dynamic inventory. Hence you're stuck using your result as what it is: a static inventory that you have to generate prior to using it. Note that inventory scripts are still supported through the script inventofy plugin but not the modern way to create a dynamic inventory. But even a script must obey certain rules, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_inventory.html#script-inventory

Comment: Or... add `ansible-inventory --list -i <file>` to the end of the script and get both!

Comment: @Jack not sure I understood your answer. You mean to generate a normal inventory file in my nodejs script than to return back to ansible the result of ansible-inventory --list -i myGeneratedInventory.txt ?

Comment: @KristiJorgji Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper solution that I am happy with, but I can make HACK around it and first call a script like

`node prepare-inventory.js && ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i preparedInv.txt`

That means that I have to pre-generate the inventory in prepare-inventory.js (this script generates and outputs preparedInv.txt) every time before calling ansible myself instead of using some ansible pre-hook or dynamic inventory feature.

It works but it is ugly and I want to use the best possible solution